# Configuring Eclipse to add a buildpath folder outside the workspace

Tags: php, eclipse, localhost

I'm developing PHP on a mac. As per other suggestions, I've set the workspace to be in the HTDOCS folder of MAMP.

Unfortunately, this means I cannot use links to '/' as I would in production.  Any suggestions?

Relatedly, the workspace seems to prevent references to build paths outside the workspace, yet I would Like to keep my sensitive files outside the base workspace folder.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the "link" feature:

- select folder in which you want to create the link (i.e. root itself);
- right-click -> new -> Folder
- click "Advanced" button
- check "Link to folder in the filesystem" and browse for the folder under htdocs

This should help

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience using eclipse with PHP, but for Java, you can "Add External Class Folder" in the "Libraries" tab of the Build Path dialog. Generally, anything that's outside the workspace is called "external" and accessible only through such special options.

Comment: This should be more clearly documented somewhere. Thanks for sharing.