# Importing other classes into this class

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to learn Java, I know this is a noob question, but bear with me please :)

Ctrl+Shift+O isn't loading my other .java file I created and I'm not sure how to tell it to.  The file is called "MyWebViewClient.java".  I'm also wondering, if I were to put this file within a folder, would it change how it's imported?

```
package com.myPackage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MyPackageClass extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //init webview
        WebView DCWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webViewSettings = DCWebView.getSettings();

        //when a link is clicked, use the WebView instead of opening a new browser
        DCWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        //enable javascript
        webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

Both classes are part of the `package com.myPackage;` package... I'm not entirely sure when I should change the name of a package.  They're also siblings of each other within /src

Answer (score 2):

Where is the `MyWebViewClient.java` file now? Also, what package declaration are you using in `MyWebViewClient.java`?

If the `MyWebViewClient.java` file is within the same package structure, you shouldn't have any problem loading it (by same package structure I mean in the same set of folders starting with `com.myPackage`.

If it is not, than you will have to tell eclipse about the other projects or folders you want on your build path. While this is in answer to a php question, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611194/configuring-eclipse-to-add-a-buildpath-folder-outside-the-workspace/611629#611629) should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

in your project you should have a src folder

in src you have your package structure so...

```
-src
--com
---myPackage
----MyPackageClass.java
----<Put second class here>
```

you dont need to import the second java class if its in the same package

Answer (score 0):

May I ask are the java files in the same package ? 
Classes can be reached they are in the same package.

Comment: Yes, it's the same package.  Both files reside within /src/MyApp/

Comment: Maybe it's not your false . You can try to clean the project.  eclipse --> project --> clean . and check it again.