# Eclipse: Share a large framework with multiple projects?

Tags: php, eclipse, frameworks, shared-libraries

We develop in PHP and HTML/Javascript.
Over time we developed a very big source code library, that contains a couple of hundred PHP and Javascript libraries, that we use for every project. The framework resides its own svn-repository, that we include with an external svn link in each project.

The problem is, that the entire framework itself is about 800MB now.
With only a few projects that we worked on, this wasn't really a problem, but now we have about 30 projects, that all contain a FULL copy of the framework, which takes up a lot of space, and requires constant updating of each copy.

Somehow I would like to have the framework *outside* the project folders. I've read about referencing other projects in Eclipse, but couldn't really get it to work. 
How do you setup the include paths so that each projet 'thinks' that the framework is normally inside the project folder?  And can you make a virtual link in an Eclipse project to edit files in the framework just as you would normally do, and get code assist for the libraries too?

One of the main problems is that all our code (and some libraries in the framework itself too) relies on the fact that the framework is in a folder 'framework' inside each project. I'd rather not change all those references to a different path, so maybe I need some `.htaccess` trick to make this work...

Does anybody else follow the same procedure?
Any advice ?

Comment: Add the framework to each projects buildpath. You can normally just configure it that way, see [Configuring Eclipse to add a buildpath folder outside the workspace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/611194/367456) and [What's the difference between the Build Path and the Include Path in Eclipse PDT?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/981956/367456).

Comment: Path Variable inside the Resource tab will help you ... Right click on your project ..Properties->Resources->Linked Resources->Path Variables... Add library inside the ${VAR}

Answer (score 0):

can you use the "big" project as target platform?

[why-create-a-custom-target-platform](http://www.modumind.com/2008/04/21/why-create-a-custom-target-platform/)

If you define it as target platform, the sources are available in your workspace, but they are placed in 1 folder for multiple workspaces. the workspaces will link to the platform, but will not check them out.